# Accessing function in bundled javascript (using webpack) from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I'm currently developing a web application and am in the process of refactoring my code so it's bundled by WebPack.

In my HTML I have a button that calls the `sendMessage()` function when clicked,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendMessage(document.getElementById('claim').value)">Submit</button>
```

In the first version of my code, the `sendMessage()` function was defined in a `.js` file that I imported directly in the HTML,

`<script src="my_js/newsArticleScript.js"></script>`

The sendMessage() function is directly declared in the file, it's not inside any class or module but it calls other functions defined on the same file, so I don't want to separate it.

But now it's being bundled by WebPack. Here is my config file (the `homepageScript.js` is for another page):

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
   homepage: './src/homepageScript.js',
   newspage: './src/newsArticleScript.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/my_js')

  }
}
```

I changed the script import on the HTML to import the bundled version.
And now, when I press the button I get the error

`[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sendMessage`

I've read about it, and I learned that webpack does not expose the functions globally. I have tried to export the function, but kept getting the same error.

Can anyone help me with this? Essentially what I need is to understant how to configure webpack or change the JS so it can be accessed by the HTML.

I'm new to JS so I'm pretty sure the way my app is designed is not the best, so any tips on improvements (maybe I should use modules, or there are better ways of calling JS function upon clicking a button) would be welcome as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally using text-based event handlers isn't a good idea. That said, you have a few options, with increasing amounts of changes.

1. For texual `onchange` handlers to work, `sendMessage` would have to be a global. So the quickest fix would be to change your code to do that. If for instance you have

   ```
   function sendMessage(arg){}
   ```

   in your code, you'd add an additional

   ```
   window.sendMessage = sendMessage;
   ```

   after it to expose it as a global variable.
2. A more modern approach would be to remove the `onchange` from the button and have the button labeled with an ID in the HTML, e.g. `id="some-button-id"`.

   Then in your JS code, you could do

   ```
   var button = document.querySelector("#some-button-id");
   button.addEventListener("change", function(){
     sendMessage(document.getElementById('claim').value);
   });
   ```

   to add the `change` handler function using JS code, instead of with HTML attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried option 1 and worked right away :) Will try option 2 later.

Answer (score 2):

To add a modern option using webpack's library output (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) you can expose your modules exports by defining an output variable for your module in your webpack config, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    ...
    library: 'MyLibrary'

  }
}
```

Now assuming you webpack entry point js file uses a `namedExport` function, you will be able to call it within your html or a subsequent script with:

```
MyLibrary.namedExport()
```

So in the original question, assuming the `newsArticleScript.js` exports the `sendMessage` function as a named export (`export const sendMessage = (arg) => ...`) and the webpack config defines the output variable `NewsArticle`, the sendMessage could be used as onclick handler with

```
<button .. onclick="NewsArticle.sendMessage(...) />
```