# How can I use a function in a bundle.js file using <script> to include the bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, bundler

I have a Javascript module called out.js

```js
export default function out(str) {   
    //Some Code 
    console.log(str); 
}
```

I ran the webpack bundler and created a bundle.js file.
And now I am Importing it to my index.html using a  tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><script defer src="bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      out("Hello")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I get the following error on the webpage.

```
index.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: out is not defined
```

I have tried named exports as well as default exports for the out.js, still I get the same error.

Comment: `window.MyFunctions.out = function(str) ...` then `<script>window.MyFunctions.out("Hello")</script>`

Comment: Also, as is mentioned in an answer, you need to get rid of the `defer` or the function won't exist when you call it.

Comment: Or you could do `window.addEventListener('load', () => window.MyFunctions.out("Hello"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browserify - How to call function bundled in a file generated through browserify in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296094/browserify-how-to-call-function-bundled-in-a-file-generated-through-browserify)

Comment: @Cully I would want to make this bundle redistributable in a way that the global namespace is not polluted.

Comment: @Cully I also don't want this function to run as soon as the page is loaded. How can It be called like a regular function?

Comment: You can run it whenever you want. You just can't run it before the script has loaded. That's why you wait for the load event. Or you could get rid of `defer`.

Comment: I did remove the defer attribute and tried calling the function. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Right, because the `out` function is still not a global.

Comment: @Cully Is there any way I can run this function without putting it in the global namespace?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could make it a library (someone else could include it in their bundle). Or just namespace everything you put on window (e.g. `window.MyLibrary.out`, `window.MyLibrary.doSomething`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good explanation and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47445906/3964217)

With my little knowledge of `javascript` and `webpack`, I spent hours looking for an answer. The short answer is you need to define your function globally to use this way. You can make `out` global by adding this block outside of your function.

```
window.out = out;
```